# NextJS Apollo Client graphql - fetch data in server side

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

First of all, i dont know why I cant paste code here, i try wrap in code tag but everytime system return error  my code is wrong formated (if anyone can  check and try paste this code I will be greatefull - I try in different way and spend for this about 30 minutes )

QUESTION:
Currently in my app data fetching is in client side when customer access in browser, then data is fetching.

How to edit this code for fetch data in server side?

example: app/page.tsx

https://pastecode.io/s/4zy2dcmy

and now in my `lib/ApolloHooks.tsx` I write hook:
https://pastecode.io/s/fu11fy4g

But this everytime fetch data in client side. I try move this code to app/page.tsx  and wrtap in get server side props, but i get error about impossible use get server side props in app.

Can anyone help me with this ? I read most of articles but still I cant resolve this.